# Specific field from XML into PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am pretty new to XML sheets in combination with PHP. I am trying to pull data from an XML file that is being returned to me via SOAP call.

My XML is being returned as this.

commented out some of the details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse>
            <result>
                <metadataServerUrl>https://...-api.salesforce.com/service...</metadataServerUrl>
                <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
                <sandbox>false</sandbox>
                <serverUrl>https://...--api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/21.0/0...</serverUrl>
                <sessionId>....</sessionId>
                <userId>....</userId>
                <userInfo>
                    <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
                    <currencySymbol>€</currencySymbol>           ...         </userInfo>
            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I am trying to pull out of this the sessionID

```
// UP HERE SOAP CALL --- return data
....... 
} else {
    $response = curl_exec($soap_do); 
    curl_close($soap_do);
    // print($response); <-- see result XML

    // grabbing the sessionid
    $xmlresponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);     
    $test = $xmlresponse->result->sessionId['value'];
    echo $test;     
}
```

This returns blank, but when I start adding the LoginResponse and the Soapenv (body and envelope), i get an error about that I am trying to get a propperty of non-object. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Why did not you use `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Doesnt work that way, @SaidbakR. I send actually a form via curl and this is the responds i get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SimpleXML you can use [`SimpleXMLElement::children`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) to find children by an XML namespace (here `soapenv`).

For your case it would something like

```
$xmlresponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);     
$response = $xmlresponse->children('soapenv', true)->Body->children('', true)->loginResponse->result->sessionId;
var_dump($response);
```

Which results in

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "...."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to say that you should use SoapClient(http://php.net/manual/tr/class.soapclient.php) for Soap Calls but if you don't want to use it, here is how you can parse this XML :

```
$xmlresponse = new SimpleXMLElement(str_ireplace([':Envelope', ':Body'], '', $response));     
$test = $xmlresponse->soapenv->loginResponse->result->sessionId['value'];
echo $test;
```

Comment: Yea, i know about the soapclient, i just prefer to do via a cURL. And thanks for the input